# Jar Sound Loading Error NullPointerException

Tags: java, audio, jar

I have the next class where it stores all the sounds i'm gonna use for a game i'm doing, however i'm trying to test the Jar file to see if is working properly and I find the next error from the command prompt

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(Unknown Source)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at Assets.AudioStreaming.loadMusicAssets(AudioStreaming.java:27)
    at CrossyMain.MainMenu.<init>(MainMenu.java:64)
    at CrossyMain.Principal.main(Principal.java:18)
```

This is the class where i'm storing all the audio assets

```
package Assets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class AudioStreaming {

private static Clip mainMenu,BGM,coinP,gameOver,trainAlert,birdGO;
private static AudioInputStream in_mainMenu,in_BGM,in_coinP,in_gameOver,in_trainAlert,in_birdGO;

public static void loadMusicAssets(){

   try{ 

   /*Background*/   
   BGM = AudioSystem.getClip();
   in_BGM = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioStreaming.class.getResource("/sound/background/NeonW.wav"));
   BGM.open(in_BGM);


   coinP = AudioSystem.getClip();
   in_coinP = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioStreaming.class.getResource("/sound/entityFx/coinPickup.wav"));
   coinP.open(in_coinP);

   gameOver = AudioSystem.getClip();
   in_gameOver = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioStreaming.class.getResource("/sound/entityFx/gameOver.wav"));
   gameOver.open(in_gameOver);

   trainAlert = AudioSystem.getClip();
   in_trainAlert = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioStreaming.class.getResource("/sound/entityFx/trainWarning.wav"));
   trainAlert.open(in_trainAlert);

   birdGO = AudioSystem.getClip();
   in_birdGO = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioStreaming.class.getResource("/sound/entityFx/eaglePickup.wav"));
   birdGO.open(in_birdGO);

   mainMenu = AudioSystem.getClip();
   in_mainMenu =  AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioStreaming.class.getResource("/sound/background/NeonValley.wav"));
   mainMenu.open(in_mainMenu);

   }catch(LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

public static void playBGM(){
    BGM.setFramePosition(0);
    BGM.start();
}

public static void stopBGM(){
    BGM.stop();
    BGM.close();
}

public static void playMainMenu(){
    mainMenu.setFramePosition(0);
    mainMenu.start();
}

public static void stopMainMenu(){
    mainMenu.stop();
    mainMenu.close();
}

public static void playTrainWarning(){
    trainAlert.setFramePosition(0);
    trainAlert.start();
}

public static void stopTrainWarning(){
    trainAlert.stop();
    trainAlert.close();
}

public static void playBirdGO(){
    birdGO.setFramePosition(0);
    birdGO.start();
}

public static void playCoinP(){
    coinP.setFramePosition(0);
    coinP.start();
}

public static void playGameOver(){
    gameOver.setFramePosition(0);
    gameOver.start();
}





}
```

It works perfectly within NetBeans with no errors whatsoever, however it sucessfully compiles the JAR file but i noticed this error with the command prompt cause it didn't want to open by just double clicking it? has anyone experienced this error? if so, how did you manage to load your sound assets to a Jar file? any tips/advices would be highly appreciated thanks for your time!

Comment: The stacktrace seems to imply that the background music (BGM) worked, but not the gameOver? Or is it just an artifact of when things are being called?

Comment: Are you sure "/sound/entityFx/gameOver.wav" exists and the program can see it?

Comment: @TheTromboneWilly yup it works normally while running on netbeans!

Comment: Use NetBeans to explore the contents of the .jar file.  You should be able to verify whether your sound file is in there.

Comment: @VGR ohh I found the culprit thanks for this tip! it works now